# Get JSON with PHP from URL and hand it over to JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

i'm stuck at a problem.
What i wanna do is to get a JSON file from a URL by using PHP (to overcome CORS issue when using AJAX) and then using JSON.parse to make it usable by JavaScript to make a list out of the JSON content.

I tried this code before but it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beispiel</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $url = "http://geoweb.zamg.ac.at/static/event/lastday.json";
        ?>

        <script>
            var array = JSON.parse(<?php file_get_contents($url) ?>);
            console.log(array);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe someone of you can help me with that problem. I'm not really good at programming yet ;)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `JSON.parse()`, because the JSON is already parsed from the file source.

You also missed to `echo` the return of file_get_contents().

```
var array = <?php echo file_get_contents($url) ?>;
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Technically it's correct, but I don't agree with this approach. If the `file_get_contents()` returns something strange, or malformatted data, the whole JavaScript will not be executed properly. It's better to fetch the contents via AJAX and handle with success and failure handler.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree. The result of `file_get_contents()` should be tested before to echo it directly. And OP should have a fallback process.

Comment: Something like this should work (cannot give an answer anymore): `try { $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR ); printf('var array = "%s";', str_replace('\'', '\\\'', 'json_encode( $data ) ) ); } catch (JsonException $ex) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: @Gregor if your codes are within JS, it might also make the whole JS fail to run. Don't do that.

Comment: @Raptor Stupid me. Actually the double quotes should be escaped and not the single ones :D `try { $data = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR ); printf('var array = "%s";', str_replace('"', '\\"', json_encode( $data ) ) ); } catch (JsonException $ex) { /* do something */ }` should be better